# need log doctrine changes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm testing a listener to make a log but do not know how to get the id of the newly created object.
The method I use is as follows:

```
class ListenerCrud{

protected $container;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}

public function onFlush(onFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
            $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
            $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

            foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() AS $entity) {
                if (!$entity instanceof Modificacion) {
                    $modificacion = new Modificacion();
                    $modificacion->setFechamod(new \DateTime('now'));
                    $className = join('', array_slice(explode('\\', get_class($entity)), -1));
                    $modificacion->setEntidad($className);
                    $modificacion->setTipo('Inserción');
                    $modificacion->setIdentificador($entity->getId()); //errorrrrrrrr
                    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
                    $modificacion->setEmpleado($securityContext->getToken()->getUser());
                    $modificacion->setInfo('');
                    $em->persist($modificacion);
                    $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($modificacion));
                    $uow->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $modificacion);
                    }
                 }
    }
}
```

where I can not access the id of the newly created object.
Could someone help me? thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$em->persist($modificacion);` you save your data to the object, but it still doesn't have `id` as you haven't assigned it. To save data to database you have to perform `$em->flush();` after which the object will get ID.

So most straitforward solution is:

```
foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() AS $entity) {
    if (!$entity instanceof Modificacion) {
        $modificacion = new Modificacion();
        $modificacion->setFechamod(new \DateTime('now'));
        $className = join('', array_slice(explode('\\', get_class($entity)), -1));
        $modificacion->setEntidad($className);
        $modificacion->setTipo('Inserción');
        $modificacion->setIdentificador($entity->getId()); //errorrrrrrrr
        $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
        $modificacion->setEmpleado($securityContext->getToken()->getUser());
        $modificacion->setInfo('');
        $em->persist($modificacion);

        $em->flush(); // now you can doSmthWithId($modificacion->getId())

        $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($modificacion));
        $uow->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $modificacion);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for a different event — [`postFlush`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#postflush) or [`postUpdate`/`postRemove`/`postPersist`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers.

the solution was:

```
    $objetos = $em->getRepository('miomioBundle:'.$className)->findAll();
    $last_item = end($objetos);
    $last_item = $last_item->getId() + 1; 
    $modificacion->setIdentificador($last_item);
```